# How to replace cv2.resize() in python

Tags: python, replace, opencv, apple-m1

I use M1 Mac. But cv2 doesn't work in M1 Mac.

I need to use the code below.

`import cv2`

`imgs_omni = np.array([cv2.resize(plt.imread(dirs), dsize=(58, 33)) for dirs in imgs_omni_dir])`

How can I replace cv2.resize to other library or code?

Comment: This blog post details how to install OpenCV on a Mac M1. https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/

Comment: You can also use pillow for reading and resizing images if you don't want to use OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

please elaborate more on why exactly cv2 doesn't work in your M1 Mac. Did you install openCV packages? And what platform are you using to implement the code? And what have you done to make sure nothing you try is not working?

There's some replacement similar to cv2, but it may or may not help due to the vagueness of your question:

1. `numpy.resize()` which can be found after importing numpy.
2. another one is the `resize()` function from skimage.

Both of the mentioned packages have well elaborated documentations. Please do, go ahead and read.